# working with registry in VBA

Tags: vba, registry

I am very new to VBA programming , I have a VBA code that reads data from  the INI file, [the function is like this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_files_ini.php) now my Boss asked me to go with registry ! Can somebody guide me what he meant ? I mean I give the input file,output file in INI file kept in some folder, but what's this registry ? How'd read put input,output file from registry?

Answer (score 3):

I believe he's asking to migrate the INI to a collection of registry strings which can populate your program configuration directly from the registry rather than the INI file. To do this, read this article on creating New Registry Keys -> [Here](https://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/11/16/how-can-i-create-a-new-registry-key.aspx)

But before you dive into messing with the registry, verify that is what your boss wants. Because messing with the registry can be a destructive end.

Answer (score 2):

Steve McMahon wrote a great registry class for vb6. You can find it here. http://www.vbaccelerator.com/codelib/inireg/registry.htm

If you intend on using it with MS Access, you'll need to replace all occurrences of App.EXEName with CurrentProject.Name.

You'll want your app to have it's own node under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software.
Good luck, and be careful not to mess with any other registry keys.

Comment: Thanks @Rich. I can't take credit for it, but it allow me build a wicked cool DSN (odbc mgr) class. If you're interested, I'll post the link to my blog once I have that written up.

Comment: Hell yeah. Post the link when you've got it posted.

Comment: @Rich Will do. Hopefully I'll have a chance to finish it this weekend.

Comment: @Rich It took me a lot longer get around to writing this up than I thought. Here's the link. http://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/vba-odbc-dsn-installer/